Postgres equivalent to oracle 'password rollover'
As above - Are there any solutions in/for postgres that allow for similar functionality to oracle's password rollover feature, where a user can have two active passwords? We are trying to implement an automatic password rotation feature, and our apps are not currently capable of automatically refreshing the credentials immediately upon connection failure.
At this time updating the applications themselves to force a refresh on connection failure is not an option. Apps run on AWS Lambda, creating datasources on a cold start. We do not want to eliminate the caching of the credentials for latency reasons

There is no equivalent that i know, you have to use a strategy like the one described here https://jannikarndt.de/blog/2018/08/rotating_postgresql_passwords_with_no_downtime/

Depending on how you're hosted, AWS offers automatic database credential rotation for PostgreSQL.

No, there is no such facility built into PostgreSQL.
For advanced authentication features, don't use password authentication in PostgreSQL. Authenticate using a central identity management service that provides such a feature. See the documentation for the supported authentication methods.
